# Can I make this code self-modify in order to add items to a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add self modifying code to this simple login system so that new accounts are saved permanently to the code. I am working on learning to code and have been googling sample projects and trying to figure them out and this is one of the suggestions that I found, but I wanted it to be a little more complex than what was suggested.

I have not been able to find any way to do this as I am fairly new to programming. I don't really even know where to go about starting to figure this out so I am hoping that someone can at least point me in the right direction or let me know if this is not possible. Currently the program simply appends any new additions to the end of the list for that specific time running the program, but I would like for any new additions to actually be permanent and change the code so that the login info will be available the next time I use the code.

````
loggedIn = False
listUsername = ["zach", "chase"]
listPassword = ["dinger", "mattingly"]
wantAccount = True

while wantAccount == True:

    account = input("Do you have an account? (yes/no): ")

    if account == "yes":
        while failedAttempts < 3 and loggedIn == False:

            print("Attempts remaining:", int(3) - int(failedAttempts))
            username = input("username: ")
            password = input("password: ")

            if username in listUsername and password in listPassword and len(listUsername) != len(listPassword) and failedAttempts > 2:
                print("maximum attempts reached. You are locked out.")
                failedAttempts = failedAttempts + 1
            elif username in listUsername and password in listPassword and len(listUsername) != len(listPassword):
                print("username and password not recognized, try again.")
                failedAttempts = failedAttempts + 1
            elif username in listUsername and password in listPassword and listUsername.index(username) != listPassword.index(password):
                print("username and password not recognized, try again.")
                failedAttempts = failedAttempts + 1

            if username not in listUsername or password not in listPassword:
                print("username and password not recognized, try again.")
                failedAttempts = failedAttempts + 1
            elif username not in listUsername or password not in listPassword and failedAttempts > 2:
                print("maximum attempts reached. You are locked out.")
                failedAttempts = failedAttempts + 1

            if username in listUsername and password in listPassword and listUsername.index(username) == listPassword.index(password):
                loggedIn = True
                print("you are logged in")
                wantAccount = False

    if account == "no":
        newAccount = input("would you like to make an account? (yes/no): ")

        if newAccount == "yes":
            newUsername = input("new username: ")
            newPassword = input("new password: ")
            listUsername.append(newUsername)
            listPassword.append(newPassword)

        if newAccount == "no":
            wantAccount = False
            pass```

I want any new additions in newUsername to be permanently added to listUsername at the end, and additions to new Password to be added to the end of listPassword. Any explanations as to how the code works would be appreciated, but I am mostly interested in simply getting this to work.
````

Comment: Hi, self modifying code is a big no-no. Passwords in plaintext are also a no-no. What you want to do is save the user names and hashed passwords in a separate file, and read the file in. Passwords are hashed so that you can tell if a given password is likely correct, but not easily guess the password itself.

Comment: also, use databases